# How do I load processes from queue and have a new process start when one finishes in Java?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, process, queue

Let's assume I have a queue of Process objects that will execute a program on my computer than is single threaded.  To increase efficiency I want to run to run 4 instances at a time so that I can get the most out of my 4 core CPU.  How do I get 4 elements out of the queue, start processing them, and have a new process from the queue take the place of a process that has finished running?

Comment: Use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)` and submit all your `Process`es in there. It has its own queue.

Comment: @Kayaman from what I can see in the Javadoc `newFixedThreadPool(4)` will return an `ExecutorService` object.  `ExecutorService.submit()`  takes an object that implements the `Runnable` interface as a parameter.  Process objects do not implement the `Runnable` interface, but the `Thread` object does. Since I can't see any way for a `Thread` object to execute a native binary like FFmpeg in my case I guess I need to make my own object that implements `Runnable` and have it use `Runtime.exec()` to run FFmpeg and pass that through to `ExecutorService.submit()`.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, you can (must) wrap your `Process` into a `Runnable` (or  `Callable` if you need to return a result). Such as `executor.submit(() -> process.doSomething());` in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Executor framework

Java provides all of this capability for you. No need for you to create your `Process` class nor a queue.

Each of your tasks should implement the `Runnable` or `Callable` interface.

Submit those to an executive service, as explained in the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). The executor service acts as your queue, feeding the submitted tasks to an available thread.

To monitor the completion of your tasks, you may capture the returned `Future` object.

If you want a maximum of four tasks to be running simultaneously, create your executor service with a backing thread pool of four threads.

But beware of over scheduling. For a four core machine, you may want to use less than four threads, if your tasks are CPU intensive. Your computer has other work to to do such as OS tasks, run the JVM, and run other apps. On the other hand, if your tasks are not CPU-intensive, so they spend much time waiting such as waiting on network calls to return, then you may want a larger thread pool.

All this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

And be sure to read the book *Java Concurrency In Practice* by Goetz et al.